# Is there any method to get SEO friendly URL from a human readable string in Hippo CMS?

Tags: hippocms

On Hippo Site I am doing a business logic to persist a bean.

I want to convert the following human readable string to SEO friendly URL

Human readable string:

To get - developers @ up to speed with Hippo CMS quickly

SEO friendly URL:

to-get---developers-up-to-speed-with-hippo-cms-quickly

What is the Hippo utility method to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Internally Hippo does something like:

```
ISettingsService settingsService = getPluginContext().getService(ISettingsService.SERVICE_ID,
            ISettingsService.class);
StringCodecFactory stringCodecFactory = settingsService.getStringCodecFactory();
return stringCodecFactory.getStringCodec("encoding.node");
```

You should be able to use that.

edit: Looking at Ilja Murasko's answer, I just realized I left out an important part. What I described gets you the proper StringCodec instance. You still have to call encode on that with the string. It is in practice the same class that Ilja is instantiating.

Comment: Which class has the implementation of  getPluginContext() method?

Comment: Its in AbstractRenderService, so any plugin has that. From the hst side I think you would have to use HippoServiceRegistry

Answer (score 1):

import org.hippoecm.repository.api.StringCodecFactory.UriEncoding;

new UriEncoding().encode("To get - developers @ up to speed with Hippo CMS quickly");

the above line returns: "to-get---developers--at--up-to-speed-with-hippo-cms-quickly"

Comment: What I posted was actually showing how to get that class. I just realised I left out the part where you actually use it. Sow without your answer my answer is incomplete. I think it is better to get the service rather than instantiate the class but your way works.

Comment: I agree, it is better to access UriEncoding via service you suggested, as direct use of UriEncoding is discouraged